# Azure DevOps pipeline yaml nested variables

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-yaml-pipelines

So I have a sql user I want to use in my pipeline. Lets say username is "fred", password is "myPass". I store sql passwords in key vault, with a secret named afther the usernames. So for in the above case, secret name would be "fred"

In a pipeline template I am creating, I am passing sql username as a parameter *MySqlUser*, so I can fetch sql username as `${{parameters.MySqlUser}}`

After fetching secrets using `task: AzureKeyVault@2`, I can access fred's password by using `$(fred)`, but if I try to use the input parameter instead of hardcoded sql username `$(${{parameters.MySqlUser}})` I get the error.

How do i "nest" parameter in there?

Answer (score -1):

In your scenario, you need to install [Variable Toolbox extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jessehouwing.jessehouwing-vsts-variable-tasks&targetId=ca4e4e67-3099-4c62-9ea9-bef80e0cc70a&utm_source=vstsproduct&utm_medium=ExtHubManageList)

[image]

And set variable before your Azure Key Vault task to be used.

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

    parameters:
      - name: MySqlUser
        displayName: Define MySqlUser
        type: string
    
    steps:
    
    - task: VariableSetTask@2
      inputs:
        variableName: 'test1'
        Value: '$(${{ parameters.MySqlUser }})'
    
    - task: PowerShell@2
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          env | sort
          echo '$(test1)'
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This answer is incorrect as it assumes that the original poster is using runtime variables, which is **not** stated anywhere.

Comment: Using runtime variables is a good option to hide the username according to poster's description.